# Software to control bass in sound?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I moved from Windows to Ubuntu, and now the music I hear with the headphones sounds with too much bass, like it is set to max.

I looked into alsamixer and pulseaudio, but I can't control bass there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 10.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:psyke83/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

Stolen from https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer

For Ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your audio player you can set equlizer in vlc.

If that won't help check this link:
http://www.unixmen.com/add-equalizer-for-pulse-audio-in-ubuntu-lucid-lynx/

Comment: I want to equalize all the sound, including sound in videos played in firefox, so vlc is not enough I think. The packages in the link didn't work for me. Have you tried them?